# ul li map selector stops another ul li from showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

New, so please excuse any toe stepping until I get the hang of this..

So I have a a script that allows a different map to be selected from a li but the script stops another li from showing.. 
[see it here](https://www.gsamin.org/a14/) It is the map selector near the bottom of the page, notice the testimonials located a bit below it has nothing under it/blank, that stops working if the map block is selected to on,  see a working  testimonials block work [here](https://marketplace.abantecart.com/)

This is the code that selects the map li

```
var googlemapselector={

selectaddr:function($addrdiv, $li, $mapiframe){
    if ($addrdiv.data('$lastselectedli'))
        $addrdiv.data('$lastselectedli').removeClass('selected')
    $li.addClass('selected')
    window.frames[$mapiframe.attr('name')].location.replace($li.data('addr')) //load map address inside IFRAME
    $mapiframe.data('$largemaplink').attr('href', $li.data('addr').replace('&output=embed', '')) 
    $addrdiv.data('$lastselectedli', $li)
},

init:function(addrwrapper, mapwrapper, persist){
    jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
        var $mapdiv=$('#'+mapwrapper)
        var $mapiframe=$mapdiv.find('iframe:eq(0)')
        var $addrdiv=$('#'+addrwrapper)
        var $lis=$addrdiv.find('ul.location:eq(0)').find('li')
        var mapiframetarget=$mapiframe.attr('name')
        var $largemaplink=$mapdiv.find('a.largermap') //ref link with class="largermap"
        $mapiframe.data('$largemaplink', $largemaplink) //remember ref to largermap link
        $lis.each(function(){
            var $li=$(this)
            var $address=$li.find('a[href^="https://www.google.com/maps"]') //find Google map links within LI
            $address.each(function(){
                var $addr=$(this)
                $addr.attr({href:this.getAttribute('href')+'embed?', target:mapiframetarget}) //add 'embed?' to Google map link plus target attribute
                $addr.click(function(e){
                    googlemapselector.selectaddr($addrdiv, $li, $mapiframe) //load Google map
                    e.preventDefault()
                })
            })
            $li.data('addr', $address.eq(0).attr('href'))
            if ($li.hasClass('selected')){
                googlemapselector.selectaddr($addrdiv, $li, $mapiframe) //load Google map
                $addrdiv.data('$lastselectedli', $li) //remember last selected LI
                return
            }
        })
    })
}
}

//parameters:
```

1. ID of DIV containing address UL,
2. ID of column containing Google map IFRAME: `googlemapselector.init('addrcolumn', 'mapcolumn')`

That is the code im using, my question is can I add a class or id that will force the script to only search for li in the addrcolum.

thank you for any help.. again sorry if I have done this wrong.

Comment: i don't get what you are saying the testimonials slideshow keeps working if i switch the map or click on it?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I can get it to work on one browser.. I have a packard bell laptop/tablet that it works as wanted/desired on, but that is it, if you try checking it on  a different browser you will see the error..the testimonials stops working, it does not show..and that is what I am trying to fix..   again..thanks for looking.  any ideas?

Comment: well you never told which browser, i checked it in mozilla and chrome and works ok ?

Comment: and what do you mean that it does not work are there any errors on console , or anything

Comment: I have an image to show you what is going on, like I stated above when the multi map block is select to on in the admin area, the testimonials ul li does not render on the page, the code is there but 9 times out of ten it will show nothing.. https://gsamin.org/bottom.png

Comment: no errors, and again the code is in the html, I was just wondering why the ul li does not show/play as it is a slide

Comment: I thought I had it figured out as maybe a https issue with the cart settings as it got it to work for a sec, but I think it was a one in 10 deal.. still perplexed as to why that does not show all the time.